# definition of $L^p$ space on the boundary

Tags: integration

Let $D$ be a bounded open set in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.

(definition)

$f\in L^1(\partial D)$ if and only if $\int_a^b |f(\gamma(t))||\gamma'(t)|dt$ is finite.

(where $\gamma$ is the parametrization of the boundary of $D$.)

I know that these definition does not depend on the choice of parametrization $\gamma$.

However, I wonder how to construct the Lebesgue measure along the curve.

Answer (score 0):

Lebesgue measure on the curve is arclength measure which is precisely how you have it up there.